# Matlab - input validation

Tags: matlab, input, validation

What is a good way to validate an input or exit the program with an error message altoghether?

For example if I take an input such as

```
Length = input('\nEnter a length in feet: ');
```

How can I check if the number is greater than 0.

something like

```
if Length > 0 then 
  %%do code
else
 %%Output error
 %%nothing to do here so it just continues and exits
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use assert:

```
assert(Length>0,'Length is less than zero, exiting.')
```

see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/assert.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Matlabs built in function `assert` (type `doc assert` or `help assert`)

```
 assert(Length > 0, 'your error msg')
```

Answer (score 3):

[Input Parser](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-11.html) is offered by MATLAB as full-blown function input 'validator'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do more advanced checking on the input string using Matlab's functions for regular expressions:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html

For example, this allows you to make sure there are only numerical characters in the input string.